# how set aria2 with uget and autostart them with starting system?

Tags: 13.10, download-manager, uget

I want to setup aria2 plugin and uget app to use downloading with aria2 by uget! 
and i want to do this autosetup and autostart by startup system.
how i can do this?

thank you

Comment: just activating the aria2 plugin makes it always enabled. If you are referring to making uGet always autostart then what version of uGet are you running? What version of Ubuntu? Did you install from our site or did you install from the Software Center?

Comment: my Ubuntu version is: 13.10 , i installed uget (version 1.10.3) from your ppa (plushuang-tw/uget-stable) . when i enable aria2 plugin, i must always use 'aria2c  --enable-rpc=true' for enabling aria2c rpc and its port for connecting uget to aria2. how can do auto enabling aria2c for using rpc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is apply the following Arguments to the Plugin Settings, click "OK", close and restart uGet.

**URI:** `http://localhost:6800/rpc`

**Path:** aria2c

**Arguments:** --enable-rpc=true -D --check-certificate=false

[image]